# Project Euler 4 while loop issues

Tags: python

So I recently started trying to solve the Project Problems, and I'm trying to solve problem 4. I wrote code that should work, but a certain while loop refuses to run. Here is the code:

```
def project_euler_problem_4():
    x = 998001
    y = 999
    while x > 10000:
        if x == int(str(x)[::-1]):
            while y > 100:
                if x % y == 0:
                    print x
                    print y
                    print x/y
                    break
                y = y -1
        x = x -1
```

The problem arises when I tried to call the while loop after the if statement. My computer science teacher nor I have any idea what's causing problems. If you could help that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You don't reset y to 999 in the outer loop. Also, this is a bizarre way of approaching the problem; much more straightforward is to multiply 100*100, 101*101, ..., 999*999 and see which of those are palindromes.

Comment: move your `y = 999` inside of your `while x> 10000:`

Comment: You do go through your `while` loop, a `print "foo"` statement in the `while` loop will prove it. And maybe you should change teacher :)

Comment: It is pretty sad you CS teacher didn't find the bug. Maybe he wasn't paying attention. Others are right, the inner while loop runs, but only once. Just keep going, PE is a great site, you will get experienced soon!

Comment: Unfortunately, he said he spent at least an hour trying to figure it out, thanks for the suggestions, but moving the y = 990 after x> 10000 didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the innermost loop, `y` will become 99. It will never be reinitialized back to 999 again. So it will only ever run once.

Change it so that `y` is set back to 999 for the next test.

```
def project_euler_problem_4():
x = 998001
while x > 10000:
    if x == int(str(x)[::-1]):
        y = 999
        while y > 100:
            if x % y == 0:
                print x
                print y
                print x/y
                break
            y = y -1
    x = x -1
```

Comment: I guess I'm going back on my previous statement about not wanting the answer, but how do you reset it to 999 after it iterates through every number.

Comment: @Devouringbowl - I didn't just copy-and-paste your code, I actually changed it. See how I moved the `y = 999` to a different place in the code.

Comment: @Devouringbowl: You're welcome. Once you've confirmed it actually works, please tick this answer.